# How to get $_GET variables in PHP containing fragment # char

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite

How to Get Variables in PHP starting with # like

```
www.example.com/api/#_dwCh_RzrIo|mp4
```

How to echo _dwCh_RzrIo variable using PHP.

```
RewriteRule ^api/#(.*)|mp4$ api.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Please correct htaccess rule and how to get #_dwCh_RzrIo variable.

Comment: It's called the "fragment", and browsers don't send it as part of the request to your site. You can't base a rewrite rule on it

Comment: If you need to send a hash character in a url, then you need to urlencode it

Comment: How urlencode will work when I cant get complete browser URL containing # fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encode fragment part i.e. starting with `#` then you can use this rule:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api/(#[^|]+) api.php?id=$1 [B,NC,L,QSA]
```

You need to test this with URL like this:

```
http://example.com/api/%23_dwCh_RzrIo%7Cmp4
```

Comment: Thanks, It works with encode but I want to resolve my indexed pages containing # so how can I redirect my pages http://example.com/api/#_dwCh_RzrIo|Cmp4 To http://example.com/api/%23_dwCh_RzrIo%7Cmp4

Comment: That needs to be done in JavaScript of by the code where you are generating HTML source containing these links.

Comment: can you write complete sample code as I'm unable to proceed it properly.